# Restarting EC2 Apache instance on CloudWatchAlarm

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I was wondering if there can be a process to restart apache if an alarm is triggered on ec2 instance. Either process can be triggered by Alarm or by SNS. In Alarm Actions i can see Auto Scaling or ECS Services or EC2 instance reboot kind option. I am trying to see if Lambda + SNS can work. But it dosen`t seem appropriate.

I am running ubuntu instances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by using Combination of AWS Lambda and EC2 Run Command Service from AWS.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/

You can create Lambda function that will trigger based on Cloudwatch Alarm and on trigger make Lambda to run `service apache2 restart` on your Ubuntu EC2 instance.

Comment: Blog seems they have not implemented for linux yet.

Comment: I have created a lambda function which SSH ec2 instance and run commands. Lambda function is triggered from SNS topic. SNS topic is integrated with a cloudwatch alarm. I am using python 2.7 in lambda function followed this thread https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/. is it possible to get EC2 public IP address which actually triggered alarm?